# Return a field from a stringified object stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, json

I have my JSON file like this:

```
{"companies":
    [{"name":"LCBO", "City":"Mississauga", "Province":"Ontario",
    "Website":"http://www.lcbo.com/content/lcbo/en.html#.WXtQ94jytPY", 
    "PhoneNumber":"1(800)668-5226", 
    "Longitude":"-79.381735", "Latitude":"43.648607"}]}
```

Here is my JavaScript to store the JSON file in local storage when the button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:'company.json',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var u = data.companies[1];
                $(u).each(function() {
                    $('#result1').append("<p>"+ "Company name: "+this.name + "<p>" +
                                        "<p>"+ "City: " +this.City + "<p>" +
                                        "<p>"+ "Province: "+this.Province + "<p>" +
                                        "<p>"+ "Website: " +this.Website + "<p>" +
                                        "<p>"+"Phone Number: "+this.PhoneNumber + "<p>" +
                                        "<p>"+"Longitude: "+this.Longitude + "<p>" +
                                        "<p>"+"Latitude: "+this.Latitude + "<p>");
                    saveData(u);
                });     
            }
        });

     function saveData(data) {
        var obj = {"Value":data};
        if (window.localStorage) {
            alert("Local Storage is supported");
            localStorage.setItem("Information", JSON.stringify(obj));
        } else {
            alert("Local Storage is not supported");
        }
    }
});
```

The question is that how I get the value "Longitude" and "Latitude" from the local storage.

Comment: can you be more clear about "GeoLocation" part? what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So I want to get the "Long and Lat" from the local storage and then I could get the position of the company based on the "Long & Lat"

Comment: Please update your title to a more meaningful one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Information'));
```

that way you'll get object stored in localStorage as a JSON object you can iterate through to get the values you want

Comment: But how do I get the value of Longitude and Latitude that is inside the 'Information'

Comment: after you parsed your localStorage data to an JSON object try to console.log that object to see its structure and values, so in my examle console.log(info); and see what you've got

Comment: it shows the list of all the items stored in local storage. Here is what I have tried but i didn't work. $("#btn6").click(function() {
  var m = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Information'));
  m.forEach(function(obj) {
   console.log(obj.Longitude);
  });
 });

Comment: can you paste here what gets logged if you console.log var m from your example

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the "Information" from localStorage, which will be a JSON string, parse it back into a javascrpt object, look in the "Value" property you created for the companies array and get an array element containing one company's data (the 0th is the first company returned from ajax), and then extract the Latitude (or Longiture) property.

```
JSON.parse(window.localStorage.get("Information")).Value.companies[0].Latitude
```

If this seems overly complicated, you can do it in steps:

```
var info = window.localStorage.get("Information");
var obj = JSON.parse(info);
var companies = obj.Value.companies;
var myCompany = companies[0];
var lat = myCompany.Latitute;
```

Also, perhaps simplify the data after ajax fetching instead of embedding it in another object.  Also, the current structure will only cache the last-retrieved ajax query.  To store multiple queries in localStorage requires either having a key for each company or pulling out the old object, updating it, and putting it back in localStorage.  There is a limit as to what is practical to store locally.